# PowerMock access private members

Tags: java, junit, mockito, private, powermock

After reading:
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation
i realized, i don't get it.

See in this example:

```
public class Bar{
   private Foo foo;

   public void initFoo(){
       foo = new Foo();
   }
}
```

How can i access the private member `foo` by using PowerMock (For example to verify that `foo`is not null)?

**Note:**
What i don't want is modifying the code with extra `get`methods.

**Edit:**
I realized that i missed a sample code block on the linked page with the solution.

**Solution:**

```
 Whitebox.getInternalState(bar, "foo");
```

Comment: I would recommend thinking carefully before writing this type of test, arguments against checking the value of private variable summarised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981476/does-jmockit-have-any-drawbacks-at-all/7499979#7499979

Comment: The real test is a bit more complex and involves hibernate, session and sessionfactory, i try to check our dbInterface without having to initialize complete hibernate stuff. In most methods we modify an objects state and have no real input/output functionality.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That should be as simple as writing the following test class:

```
public class BarTest {
    @Test
    public void testFooIsInitializedProperly() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        // Act
        bar.initFoo();

        // Assert
        Foo foo = Whitebox.getInternalState(bar, "foo");
        assertThat(foo, is(notNull(Foo.class)));
    }
}
```

Adding the right (static) imports is left as an exercise to the reader :).

Comment: Yes i somehow overlooked the code sample on the page. Your answer is correct

Comment: I like the "Arrange, Act, Assert" comments. I use "Setup, Test, Validate" but like the ring of the 3 As.

Comment: I actually switched from S-T-V to A-A-A. The alliteration indeed makes it sound nice. But most importantly (with either abbreviation): it helps you structure your test, making it harder to accidentally test your mock instead of your SUT. I've seen that happen - due to the three phases being mixed.

Comment: answer to the exercise for private static bar: Foo foo = Whitebox.getInternalState(Bar.class, "foo"); for you can get static field directly through class rather than instance :)